Using API's Enum keys in React select component as dropdown values
i'm working on my C# Asp.NET + React CRUD application.
I want to use my api's enum values(or keys? whatever) as values that you can select from in dropdown selection component.
So lets say i want to create and add to the database a new Item record and i want to be able to set the correct ItemType, ideally from a dropdown menu so i won't misspell anything.
Lets say this is my enum and my Item class:
public enum ItemType
    {
        ChargeBoard,
        LCD,
        Battery,
        Speaker,
        Buzzer
        //etc...
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public ItemType? Type { get; set; }
        //other irrelevant properties like name, price etc.
    }

Whenever I send a GET request to my api I get a string value from my Type property (so it'll be type:"LCD" for example) which is just a single key from n possible keys that exist on my backend side of application.
So how do i get all possible keys that my ItemType enum has?
Ofc I could just hardcode an array for that, but every time something changes on backend i'd need to readjust it on my frondend side too, which isn't exactly a great idea.
The first and only thing that came to my mind so far is to make a separate endpoint in my API that'll get me every possible enum key as a string value.
Maybe someone has better (cleaner?) ideas?

Here is how I would approach this:

Create an Api endpoint to GET the values of your enum
Call that endpoint with react, get all values and map them to your dropdown
In your POST request for the item, the dropdown should automaticaly fill the JSON's item type with the corresponding selected string

Hope this helps!
Sources used:
Source 1
Source 2
Source 3
